# is there a way to get user created playlists using the youtube java library?

Tags: java, youtube

I have code like this; and it works fine. but I would like only user created lists. Is this possible?

```
 */
                ChannelListResponse clr = youtube.channels()
                        .list("contentDetails").setMine(true).execute();

                // Get the user's uploads playlist's id from channel       list  
                // response
                String uploadsPlaylistId = clr.getItems().get(0)
                        .getContentDetails().getRelatedPlaylists()
                         // I want user created lists not uploads or                                
                         // favorites
                         .getUploads();
```

Comment: I found the answer here after more searching Sorry

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795665/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-videos-available-from-a-particular-youtube-channel

Answer (score 0):

I have just looked at [youtube data api v3](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/) (I didn't use before just looked at api.).

It seems, it provides PlaylistListResponse then you can get Playlist items and theirs ids.